# How can i get in choices=max_guest by room_id when I create django.models?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

I have model like this:

```
class KeyTransfer(Model):
    key_out_data = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    key_in_data = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    room_id = ForeignKey(Room, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)
    guests = IntegerField(choices=[(x, str(x)) for x in range(Room.objects.get(number=room_id).max_guests)], blank=True, null=True)
    notes = CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    person_id = ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=SET_NULL)
```

and i understand that i can`t save some value in column "guests" with argument "choices=" as you can see above.
In a consequence I have gotten error:

```
...django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet. ...
```

and i see what this error means.

**The question is:** can I realise some similar condition for "choices" in "guests" do not using django.forms?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Even django forms wouldn't help you because of the form html rendering on the server side and the guests field will not update on room_id is changed. You need to use django.forms with sending ajax request every time you choose the room to get available guests number from Room instance and dynamically set the number into correspondent form input.

Comment: @artembo, thx, I see you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to set upper limit for `guests` field of `KeyTransfer` model based on its related `room` model's `max_guests` field. You can do that by overriding `save` method and check there if assigned `guests` is higher than `max_guests`. See below implementation of this approach:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Person {}>".format(self.name)


class Room(models.Model):
    max_guests = models.IntegerField()


class KeyTransfer(models.Model):
    key_out_data = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    key_in_data = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    room_id = models.ForeignKey('Room', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    guests = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    person_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        room = self.room_id
        if self.guests > room.max_guests:
            raise ValidationError("Assigned guests exceeding related room's maximum limit of {}"\
                                  .format(room.max_guests))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This code will work but this solution is not user friendly enough. Thus, the user does not know the limit of guests for selected room.

Comment: @artembo agreed and edited error message to reflect max_guests also

Comment: This implementation is quite enough for me. Thx for good explanation.